# Display Updated Wallet Balance After Transaction Confirmed

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, react, nextjs, balance

i'm learning solana development from Buildspace and this is the tutorial source code for the next.js app
https://github.com/buildspace/solana-send-sol-frontend.git

the component to display the solana balance in the connected wallet is here:
https://github.com/buildspace/solana-send-sol-frontend/blob/main/components/BalanceDisplay.tsx

after a transaction to send solana is confirmed, the balance shown on the frontend does not update.

how can i change the code so that the balance is updated?

Answer (score 2):

figured out a solution with `onAccountChange`

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange

here's my solution
https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-send-sol-frontend/pull/4/files

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to get the new balance:

either you query again the blockchain with `getParsedAccountInfo(wallet_address)` and you will get the new SOL balance (check https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedAccountInfo)

either you fetch the transaction with `getParsedTransaction(signature)` and you will get the new SOL balance in postBalances (check https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransaction)